# Providing data to Polymer elements

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer, web-component

I want to have a single source provide all of my data. A model if you will, and I want my elements to be able to utilize that data, but never change it (one way data-binding). How can I go about this? Should I add the data as a behavior?

I tried doing this in my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/data.js"></script> <!-- defines a global object named DATA -->
<my-element data="{{DATA}}"></my-element>
```

And this inside my-element.html

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template></template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        data: Object
      },
      ready: function () {
        console.log(this.data);
      }
    });
  </script>
</my-element>
```

but it doesn't seem to work, the value of this.data is literally "{{data}}".

I am looking for a better solution than wrapping the element declaration inside a `dom-bind` template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use data binding, you either need to use it inside a polymer element, or inside a dom-bind element. See the explanation [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind). If you use dom-bind, it's only a case of using the js to set DATA to a property on the dom-bind template element, 'data' maybe, which would be little code.

Essentially, you can't set a global and expect data binding to know about it. You need to either tell dom-bind about it, or the element about it, by setting a property on the element, perhaps using behaviour, as you suggested, or using Mowzer's approach.

An example of using a behaviour would be:

```
<link rel="import" href="databehaviour.html"> 
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="an-ele">

    <style>
    </style>
    <template>
        <div>{{data.sth}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "an-ele",
            behaviors: [DataBehaviour]
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

With the behaviour being:

```
<script>
    DataBehaviour = {
        ready: function() {
            this.data = {'sth':'A thing! A glorious thing!'};
        }
    }
</script>
```

But in your case, `this.data` would be set to your `DATA` global.

Comment: I understand that. The `Polymer` function call that I am making is inside a Polymer element's script tag.

Comment: Thing is, `<my-element data="{{DATA}}"></my-element>` is outside a polymer element, or dom bind, so it doesn't know what DATA is, or data binding is, for that matter.

Comment: Your best bet is to set the DATA global to an element property, ignoring data binding outside the elements altogether, using a behaviour most likely.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how I could do this with a behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Use `<iron-meta>` [[link](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta)] or `<iron-localstorage>]` [[link](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-localstorage)] to share variables between elements or the main document.